# Applet for opening a file on a local machine but save in a cloud drive

Tags: java, applet, cloud, drive

I've seen an applet that will allow you to click on a file on a cloud drive (i.e on a web page), it then opens the file locally with the relevant app, and when you click save, the file is saved to the cloud drive.

I've tried searching for similar applets but can find nothing. Can anybody point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like WebDAV functionality.  Maybe something like "DAV Explorer" https://www.ics.uci.edu/~webdav/installation.html is what you want.

If not, try searching for other WebDAV applets.

Comment: A-ha :)  I get it now. Would you say this sounds correct. You create a virtual file system, with just the one file and mount this under the local system. You can then open the relevant app for that file. When the App is closed, you dismount your system :)